# query on mark pieter article on pe_coff spec

Tags: c++, c, assembly

In first 2 pages, layout diagram of PE executable and COFF format is given.

So, my question is,

I assume windows object files and executables are in COFF format, SO WHAT IS PE EXECUTABLE FORMAT?

Sham

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft PE and COFF Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx):

> This specification describes the structure of executable (image) files and object files under the Windows family of operating systems. These files are referred to as Portable Executable (PE) and Common Object File Format (COFF) files, respectively.

Comment: Hello                              My question is, On page 10, 11 i see two different diagrams for binary files. One is PE layout and other is COFF layout.

Comment: So, my question is,

I assume windows object files and executables are in COFF format, SO WHAT IS PE EXECUTABLE FORMAT?                                                      Sham

Comment: There's one common format that differs somewhat between executables and object files. Read the spec.

Comment: Hello Alexey                     As per your update"This specification describes the structure of executable (image) files and object files under the Windows family of operating systems. These files are referred to as Portable Executable (PE) and Common Object File Format (COFF) files, respectively."                           #########  Do you mean, executable(image) files are in Portable executable format and Object files are COFF format, am i correct?      Thx